# Assigning a single value to multiple AngularJs $scope variables same as in regular JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the preferred or easiest way to assign a single `value` to multiple AngularJs `$scope variables`?

Would one do it in the same way you would do normal JavaScript variables?:

```
var a, b, c, d, e;
a = b = c = d = e = 'new value';
```

The issue I see with this is, I do not declare my `$scope` variables before assignment, unless it is an `object` or `array`.

Example: I would simply declare:

```
$scope.a = 1;
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.a;
$scope.a = 1;
```

What worries me, is if the `$scope variables` are not declared, you would create a `reference` to another `variable`, instead of assigning the `value`:

Example:

```
$scope.a = $scope.b = $scope.c = $scope.d = $scope.e = 'new value';
```

So, must I first declare the `$scope variables` before using the normal JavaScript assignment of a single `value` to multiple `variable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine:

```
$scope.a = $scope.b = $scope.c = $scope.d = $scope.e = 'new value';
```

You don't need to "declare" the properties.

The reason you declare them first, in the plain JS example, is tho prevent the variables from polluting the global scope:

This:

```
var a, b, c, d, e;
```

Declares all the variables in a local scope.

You don't have to do that with the angular variables, since they're already scoped to `$scope`.